# Is it possible to extend a migration? And if so, is it a good practice?

Tags: laravel

I have two models that are identical in terms of table structure, but I want to keep them separated to take advantage of something like this:

`FirstModel::all()`

My goal is to have a parent migration extended by these two models' migrations, even if they're empty, just for the above reason. Moreover, I really can't stand to copy and paste their structure between two migration files.

Here is the parent migration:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateParentModelTable extends Migration
{
     /**
      * Run the migrations.
      *
      * @return void
      */
      public function up()
      {
          Schema::create('parent_model', function (Blueprint $table) {
              $table->bigIncrements('id');
              $table->timestamps();
          });
      }

      /**
      * Reverse the migrations.
      *
      * @return void
      */
      public function down()
      {
          Schema::dropIfExists('parent_model');
      }
}
```

Here is the first model migration:

```
use App\Database\Migrations\CreateParentModelTable;

class CreateFirstModelTable extends CreateParentModelTable
{
    /**
    * Run the migrations.
    *
    * @return void
    */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('first_model', function (Blueprint $table) {
            //
        });
    }

    /**
    * Reverse the migrations.
    *
    * @return void
    */
   public function down()
   {
       Schema::dropIfExists('first_model');
   }
}
```

The second model migration is identical, of course.
Now... I know that this code cannot work because there should be something that actually pulls in the parent model migration, since extending its class is not enough, but the very first problem is that I received a strange error:

```
Class 'Database\Migrations\CreateParentModelTable' not found
```

Why? Beyond that, what about the real question of this post?

**EDIT:** The timestamps in front of *CreateParentModelTable* that Laravel adds automatically cannot be used when importing. That's why I tried that way.

**PRACTICAL SOLUTION:** I just created two migrations since I've been convinced they serve two different purposes, even if in the same way.

Comment: Why don't you just use something like `CREATE TABLE first_model LIKE parent_model` in a raw query?

Comment: _the very first problem is that I received a strange error_ The class name must correspond to the filename `0000_00_00_000000_create_parent_model_table.php`  Eventually, you will need to do a `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: Hi @DanieGraziani personally I don't think you need to feel bad about copying and pasting between migrations. Migrations aren't exactly part of your application code and in my opinion they should be optimised for readability. I'd also consider why your tables are very identical (or very similar). Perhaps you only need one table with an extra `type` column, for example.

Comment: I deleted my previous comment to better match the status of the post. I agree with you: probably it's good practice to have two migrations for two different models even if they're identical. I will go for it!

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessarily need two migration files for this. A migration is, simply put, a batch of actions that modify the database in some way or another. What parts of the database you change within a migration is something you have to decide on your own. It is indeed *recommended* to use one migration file per table, but if it makes sense in a given scenario, you can also do it differently.

Your approach with inheritance of the migration classes would work if done correctly:

```
class CreateParentModelTable
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create($this->table, function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

   public function down()
   {
       Schema::dropIfExists($this->table);
   }
}

class CreateFirstModelTable extends CreateParentModelTable
{
    protected $table = 'first_model';
}

class CreateSecondModelTable extends CreateParentModelTable
{
    protected $table = 'second_model';
}
```

One alternative approach would be to use the same closure with the same options to create both tables in the same migration file:

```
public function up()
{
    $tableOptions = function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->timestamps();
    };

    Schema::create('first_model', $tableOptions);
    Schema::create('second_model', $tableOptions);
}

public function down()
{
    Schema::dropIfExists('second_model');
    Schema::dropIfExists('first_model');
}
```

And another solution would be to avoid creating two equal tables by creating a table that can store both in a polymorphic way:

```
class CreatePolymorphicModelTable
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('polymorphic_model', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->enum('type', ['first', 'second']);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

   public function down()
   {
       Schema::dropIfExists('polymorphic_model');
   }
}
```

Depending on the type of table (i.e. if it's a child table in a 1:n relationship or not), it makes sense to adhere to the polymorphic table and relationship guidelines described in the official [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relationships).

Comment: Seems good! I will surely try the first approach! Thanks allot :)

Comment: Unfortunately the first approach doesn’t work: I canno split the three classes (parent and children) in three separate files. Using and extending the parent class cannot be done because it throws “Class not found”. I tried everything thinking it was about the file name but nothing. I’m keeping it this way :(

Comment: Maybe try running `composer dump-autoload` after creating the files. I'm using cross-references between migration classes myself, so they have to be found. If that doesn't work, try adding `"database/migrations"` to the `autoload.classmap` array in `composer.json`. Then re-run `composer dump-autoload`.

Answer (score 0):

Update: I spoke to a colleague about this, who pointed out that if the methods used to add the common columns are ever updated, these changes won't be reflected in any tables which have already been migrated (unless migrations are run fresh) - so this is potentially not a great idea, as it could cause issues or confusion in production, or in later development if you've added or removed 'common' columns in later migrations.

I'll leave the answer below for info anyway, but this is potentially not something you'd really want to be doing - in this case, probably better to just copy-and-paste those columns! :)

---

I had a similar scenario in that I have a number of tables which will have some columns in common.  I wanted to create a 'base' migration which could be used to add these common columns.

I created a class BaseMigration.php in the migrations folder which I extended in my migration files, but was getting the same error that the class couldn't be found. Dumping autoload etc didn't resolve.

In the end I found if I put BaseMigration into a subfolder in the app directory, with a namespace of something like `App\DatabaseHelpers`, I was able to import and use this in my migrations.  So maybe something weird about the database or migrations folders that are preventing the file being found?

---

For anyone interested, I added the common columns with methods as below:

```
// BaseMigration.php

    protected function addCommonColumns(Blueprint $table): Blueprint
    {
        $table->id();
        $table->uuid('internal_id');
        $table->string('original_id');
        $table->string('common_reference');

        return $table;
    }
```

Then in the actual migration file, I call the method from BaseMigration, passing in the `$table` variable, which is returned.

```
// actual migration file

use App\DatabaseHelpers\BaseMigration;

return new class extends BaseMigration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('some_table', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $this->addCommonColumns($table);
            // add other columns as normal
    ...
```

This means I can have migrations which are different, but have some common fields.  This could potentially also be done with just a helper class that is imported into the migration file, rather than by extending a base class.